# My sticky navbar js script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, navbar

I can't get the sticky navbar to work. It is supposed to stick to the top once you scroll over the header.
Am I not triggering the right classes?

```
var n=$(".navbar");
ns=".navbar-scrolled";
head=$('header').height();
$(window).scroll(function()  {
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > head) {
            n.addClass(ns);
        }
        else {
            n.removeClass(ns);

        }
```

Here's the [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jsuc4kL5/)

Comment: Remove dot in add or remove class. var ns="navbar-scrolled";

Comment: Tried that before ... no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `.` to add new class attribute.
`ns` and `head` is a variable, so you should add `var` before the statement or you can separate it by comma.

Here's working demo
https://jsfiddle.net/alfrcr/jsuc4kL5/2/